# How to accomplish relative import in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, relative-path, python-packaging

Consider:

```
stuff/
    __init__.py
    mylib.py
    Foo/
        __init__.py
        main.py
        foo/
            __init__.py
            script.py
```

`script.py` wants to import `mylib.py`.

This is just an example, but really I just want to do a relative import of a module in a parent directory. I've tried various things and get this error...

`Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

I read somewhere that the script from where the program starts shouldn't reside in the package, and I tried modifying the structure for that like so...

```
stuff/
    mylib.py
    foo.py // Equivalent of main.py in above
    foo/
        __init__.py
        script.py
```

But I got the same error.

How can I accomplish this? Is this even an adequate approach?

In Python 2.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After fiddling with it a bit more, I realized how to set it up, and for the sake of specificity I won't use foo bar names. My project directory is set up as...

```
tools/
    core/
        object_editor/
            # files that need to use ntlib.py
            editor.py # see example at bottom
            __init__.py
        state_editor/
            # files that need to use ntlib.py
            __init__.py
        ntlib.py
        __init__.py # core is the top level package
    LICENSE
    state_editor.py # equivalent to main.py for the state editor
    object_editor.py # equivalent to main.py for the object editor
```

A line in `object_editor.py` looks like...

```
from core.object_editor import editor
```

A line in `editor.py` looks like...

```
from .. import ntlib
```

or alternatively

```
from core import ntlib
```

The key is that in the example I gave in the question, the "main" script was being run from within the package. Once I moved it out, created a specific package (`core`), and moved the library I wanted the editors to share (`ntlib`) into that package, everything was hunky-dory.

Comment: You've got it. What's going on is that you can't use relative imports from the script that you're running from the command line, so that should be at the top level of organisation, referring to things below it.

Comment: Why the "main" script was being run from within the package cause the problems ?

Answer (score 14):

Though as long as "stuff" is not in your Python PATH, you haven't got any choice than adding the path.

If you know the level of your *script.py* from stuff, you can do, for example:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Not that I don't believe you, but in the case of just wanting to say "hey import from 2 directories up" requires modifying the system path, I've gotta see it with my own eyes.

Comment: This is what I usually end up doing, if only out of spite.

Comment: I wouldn't say its exactly documented like this.  though I used this multiple times myself. It will just modify the system path for your running python script, not globally in the system anyway. I think you should not mind. :P

Comment: Works great, particularly for unit tests, where you just cannot change the layout.

Comment: `env PYTHONPATH=..  python myfile.py `
Is another way as well

Comment: The problem with this is that most (all?) python IDEs won't always honour this and will therefore flag the imports as unresolvable errors, breaking indexing and almost everything useful about the IDE. In some (e.g. PyCharm) this can be resolved somewhat by manually specifying the correct 'root' for the absolute imports in the project settings. However I haven't been able to get this to work with relative imports at all, so far.

Comment: In the end you should not really have to do this though. This answer is already quite old, but I believe that I never had to do this since then. It is all about good dependency management and how you structure your project.

Answer (score 7):

I'm running Python 3.4.2 on Windows 7 and tore my hair out over this.

When running either of these:

> python -m unittest
>   python -m unittest discover

...I would get the 'Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package' error.

For me, the solution was dropping the ".." in my [test_stock.py].
The line was: 
  from ..stock import Stock

Changed it to: 
  from stock import Stock

.. and it works.

Folder structure:

```
C:\
  |
  +-- stock_alerter
             |
             +-- __init__.py
             +-- stock.py
             |
             \-- tests
                   |
                   +-- __init__.py
                   \-- test_stock.py
```

Comment: Your solution works but I can't understand why...Plus, Pycharm is getting crazy with this and red-highlight the statement

Comment: It works because it's no longer a relative import when you remove the `..`. Instead it's an absolute import. PyCharm will use the project's source directory to resolve it, which means you might need to manually add a directory in the project settings to help it resolve the imports.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports) it appears that you cannot use a relative import to import a file that is not packaged.

So you would need to add a `__init__.py` to stuff and change your imports to something like `from .mylib import *`

However, the PEP seems to make no allowance to keep mylib packaged up in a module. So you might be required to change how you call your library functions.

Another alternative is to move mylib into a subpackage and import it as `from .libpackage import mylib`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux or perhaps a similar Unix-like system, you can hack this with [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

```
stuff/
    mylib.py
    foo.py // equivalent of main.py in above
    foo/
        script.py
        mylib.py  ->  ../mylib.py
    foo2/
        script2.py
        mylib.py  ->  ../mylib.py
```

This is likely not a good pattern to follow.

In my case, I opted for it, because I had multiple executables dependent on the same library that needed to be put into separate directories.

Implementation of new executable tests shouldn't require the test writer to have a deep understanding of Python imports.

```
tests/
    common/
        commonlib.py
    test1/
        executable1.py
        executable2.py
        commonlib.py -> ../common/commonlib.py
    test2/
        executable1.py
        executable2.py
        commonlib.py -> ../common/commonlib.py
```