# Python relative-import script two levels up

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, directory-structure, relative-import

I've been struggling with imports in my package for the last hour.

I've got a directory structure like so:

```
main_package
 |
 | __init__.py
 | folder_1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | folder_2
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | script_a.py
 |  |  | script_b.py
 |
 | folder_3
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | script_c.py
```

I want to access code in `script_b.py` as well as code from `script_c.py` from `script_a.py`. How can I do this?

If I put a simple `import script_b` inside `script_a.py`, when I run

```
from main_package.folder_1.folder_2 import script_b
```

I am met with an

```
ImportError: no module named "script_b"
```

For accessing `script_c.py`, I have no clue. I wasn't able to find any information about accessing files two levels up, but I know I can import files one level up with

```
from .. import some_module
```

How can I access both these files from `script_a.py`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to accomplish this relative import in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655526/how-to-accomplish-this-relative-import-in-python)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

To access script_c and script_b from script_a, you would use:

```
from ...folder_3 import script_c
from . import script_b
```

Or if you use python3, you can import script_b from script_a by just using:

```
import script_b
```

However, you should probably use absolute imports:

```
from mypackage.folder_3 import script_c
from mypackage.folder1.folder2 import script_b
```

Also see: [Absolute vs Relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209641/absolute-vs-explicit-relative-import-of-python-module)

Comment: What about accessing `script_b`?

Comment: What is `...` mean?

Comment: @mrgloom It means move up two directories: current dir: `.` up one dir: `..` up two dirs: `...`.

Comment: `import ...utility_functions.plot_figures as plotfgs
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Python shows a syntax error for ...

Comment: It doesn't work for me: Having `from ...folder_3 import script_c` in `script_a.py` and running it `python script_a.py` gives me `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I'm using Python 3.7.

Comment: @Lei, you can't use _relative_ imports in `script_a.py` when running `python script_a.py`. You can get rid of the relative import and either `cd ../../ && python $OLD_PWD/script_a.py` or `PYTHONPATH=../../ python script_a.py` or create a top-level script and turn the old script into a module