# How to import python script from a different directory using relative paths?

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
main_package
 | __init__.py
 | folder_1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | folder_2
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | script_a.py
 |
 | folder_3
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | script_c.py
```

All the `__init__.py` files are empty.
Here are the contents of the other three files.

script_a.py:

```
from ...folder_3 import script_c


print "Hello from script_a"
```

script_c.py:

```
print "Hello from script_c"
```

When I try to run `script_a.py` as shown below, it fails. This is exactly the opposite of the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36826908/1742777).

How can I run `script_a.py` and import `script_c.py` into it? I'm using Python 2.71

```
$ pwd
main_package/folder_1/folder_2

$ python ./script_a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script_a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ...folder_3 import script_c
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Comment: Try running as a module with the `-m` flag, explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22250157/1034677)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python/7506029#7506029)

and suggested by @tim in the comment section, if you run script by adding `-m` it might work.

There is another way (a.k.a the `hacker way`) suggested in the same topic I sent you the link.

**EDIT:**

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..', 'folder_3'))
import script_c
```

This one worked for me. Could you try please? Is it okay for you to import like that?

Comment: Yes. The Hacker Way worked. Thanks. But oh god is it ugly......