# Relative import of python module from current working directory

Tags: python, python-module, relative-import

In the current working directory , i have following structure

```
Project
   __init__.py
   -RestApi
           __init__.py
           app.py
           query_generator
   -testfolder
           __init__.py
           test1.py
```

I want to call query_generator from test1.py , I tried calling

```
 from . RestApi.query_generator import *
```

but getting following error

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This question might be duplicate of following [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) , [Python relative-import script two levels up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826839/python-relative-import-script-two-levels-up), [Attempted relative import with no known parent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084977/attempted-relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package) . But I am not able to solve it for my current problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below import:

```
from Project.RestApi.query_generator import *
```

Comment: from ProjectAware.RestApi.query_generator import *  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProjectAware'

Comment: getting ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Did you executing file like: python testfolder/test1.py ?

Comment: Yes I am doing that

Comment: Can you check your python path and verify that your CWD is present in python path after executing this file?
Use sys module for this. Just print(sys.path)

Comment: i have added the path using sys.path.insert(1, 'U:\\ProjectAware')

Comment: ['u:\\ProjectAware', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\dbconnect\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\dbconnect', 'C:\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\restapi-0.0.1-py3.7.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProjectAware' , still getting same error

Comment: This is strange. Bcz if your CWD is present in python path. there should not be any error like ProjectAware.

Comment: After adding RestApi to path its worked fine. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.
you can add path till `Project` dir in your `PYTHONPATH` variable

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<path_leading_to_Project>/Project
```

Then inside `test1.py` you can import the `query_generator` module using:

```
from RestApi.query_generator import *
```

Advantage of doing in such a way is if you execute your script from any working directory, it will work