# Python import module from within module in another subpackage

Tags: python, import, package

I am having trouble importing a module from within another module. I understand that that sentence can be confusing so my question and situation is exactly like the one suggested here:  [Python relative-import script two levels up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826839/python-relative-import-script-two-levels-up)

So lets say my directory structure is like so:

```
main_package
 |
 | __init__.py
 | folder_1
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | folder_2
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | script_a.py
 |  |  | script_b.py
 |
 | folder_3
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | script_c.py
```

And I want to access code in script_b.py as well as code from script_c.py from script_a.py.

I have also followed exactly what the answer suggested with absolute imports.

I included the following lines of code in script_a.py:

```
from main_package.folder_3 import script_c
from main_package.folder1.folder2 import script_b
```

When I run script_a.py, I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_package'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `python` doesn't know where to find `main_package` in `script_a.py`.

There are a couple of ways to expose `main_package` to `python`:

1. run `script_a.py` from `main_package`'s parent directory (say `packages`). Python will look for it in the current directory (`packages`), which contains `main_package`:

   ```sh
   python main_package/folder_1/folder_2/script_a.py
   ```
2. add `main_package`'s parent directory (`packages`) to your `PYTHONPATH`:

   ```sh
   export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/packages"; python script_a.py
   ```
3. add `main_package`'s parent directory (`packages`) to `sys.path` in `script_a.py`

   In your `script_a.py`, add the following at the top:

   ```py
   import sys
   sys.path.append('/path/to/packages')
   ```

Comment: The method `python main_package/folder_1/folder_2/script_a.py` won't add the parent directory of `main_package` to `sys.path`, so it won't work and you'll get `ModuleNotFoundError`. A better alternative is to use: `python -m main_package.folder_1.folder_2.script_a`.