# VSCode import files from other folders

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import, intellisense, python-module

I have such project structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── models
    ├── model1.py
    ├── model2.py
├── connectors.py
    ├── model1_connector.py
    ├── model2_connector.py
```

I start application using `python app.py`.
Inside of `app.py` I use

```
from models.model1 import Model1
from models.model1 import Model1
from connectors.model1_connector import Connector1
from connectors.model2_connector import Connector2
```

it works perfectly.
But in the `connectors` I use next code:

```
from models.model1 import Model1
```

It works on running application, because I start application from `.` and at start it can recognize all paths correctly. But when I'm working in VSCode its Intellisence craches: when I work in `connectors.model1_connector` it can't find `model` folder, because it is in parent folder! I can't use help, can't use `Ctrl+click`, can't use `Tab` and so on.

I know I can solve it using `sys.append('../' but I suppose it is not correct - I dont need it for real project to start I need it just for comfort work in VSCode!

What is the best solution here?

Comment: Relative imports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655526/how-to-accomplish-relative-import-in-python

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? You are also missing `__init__.py` files in both your `model` and `connectors` directories which would probably help.